# Java 7 -> Cannot infer Type with Comparator

Tags: java, java-7

When I use java 7 to compile a code using PriorityQueue with Comparator, compiler sends error:

```
 cannot infer type arguments for Comparator<T>;
    Comparator<Map.Entry<Double, PureColor>> colorComparator  = new Comparator<>() {
                                                                              ^
  reason: cannot use '<>' with anonymous inner classes
```

Why this, and how can I compile me code:

```
    Comparator<Map.Entry<Double, PureColor>> colorComparator  = new Comparator<Map.Entry<Double, PureColor>>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(Map.Entry<Double, PureColor> o1, Map.Entry<Double, PureColor> o2) {
        return o1.getKey().intValue() - o2.getKey().intValue();
      }
    };

    PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Double, PureColor>> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(colorComparator);
```

Comment: *"how can I compile me code"* You already wrote the code to specify the type parameter (`new Comparator<Map.Entry<Double, PureColor>>() { ... }`), instead of using the `<>` diamond operator, so that code should compile fine. Why are you asking how you can make your code compile, when you already did?

Comment: If you get this code and put on Java 7 compiler will throw an error, even if I put types inside diamond operator.

Comment: Perhaps, but not the error you've shown. The code and the error is not consistent with each other, so please provide *valid* [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ***Unable to reproduce:*** That `colorComparator` code tested with JDK 1.7.0_79 and compiles without error, assuming a `PureColor` exists.

Comment: If you get this code and put on Java 7 compiler, the error is exactly that. But you need to use JAVA 7 compiler

Comment: Error message says `new Comparator<>()`, code says `new Comparator<Map.Entry<Double, PureColor>>()`, ergo *that* code does ***not*** produce *that* error message!!! --- And if you code is really using the `<>` diamond operator, then please(!) read my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043817/java-7-cannot-infer-type-with-comparator?noredirect=1#comment102488187_58043817).

Comment: But perhaps, it’s a good thing that your compiler stopped you on that, as `o1.getKey().intValue() - o2.getKey().intValue()` is a horribly broken comparator implementation logic.

Comment: @Holger compare most return an nit and i have two double, soo i did use intValue(), how can i mais it better?

Comment: If you think, just because the return type is an `int`, any `int` will do, just carry on. Otherwise, if you want to implement *comparator logic*, consider that even when comparing two `int` values, the difference between two values can be larger than the `int` value space, leading to overflow. But you are comparing *double* values, which have an even larger value space. You are cutting off the fractions and cutting down values with a large magnitude. Not to speak of special cases like NaN. And it’s not even simpler than a correct, straight-forward `return o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey());`

Answer (score 2):

It is a limitation in java-7 the `<>` operator is not supported for anonymous classes

[Class Instance Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)

**It is a compile-time error if a class instance creation expression declares an anonymous class using the "<>" form for the class's type arguments.**

But from jdk-9 `<>` operators is supported for anonymous classes

[What’s New for the Java Language in JDK 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-825576B5-203C-4C8D-85E5-FFDA4CA0B346)

**Allow the diamond with anonymous classes if the argument type of the inferred type is denotable.**

So to resolve this issue either upgrade java 7 to java 9 or just define the generic parameters like second approach in your example

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Double, PureColor>> colorComparator  = new Comparator<Map.Entry<Double, PureColor>>()
```